# Make each one svn commit as one git commit

Tags: git-svn

I organize one repository with both git and svn.  svn is for collaboration.  git is my own management because I like to make many many commits and branches but do not want to intefere with other people.

With say 10 git commits, I svn commit once manually.  So never need to sync git => svn.

Currently when I see new svn commits, I update svn, then make a commit in git.  This one git commit may include several svn commits.

**I would like to do:  sync every svn => git**.

That is, to make EACH ONE svn commit as one git commit.

Ideally with the same commit log.

More ideally each git commit comes with a tag or extra log stating the svn commit number.

Can it be done?  With git-svn?

Comment: yes. git-svn is exactly what you need.

Answer (score 2):

If you were to use git svn, then you would not put your git repo inside the svn workspace.

You could [`git svn clone`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-svn#git-svn-emcloneem) the repo, and [`git svn rebase`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-svn#git-svn-emrebaseem) at will, while making your own commit in a separate branch of that Git repo.
The svn rebase process would create one git commit per svn revision (but not with the same comment though)